# Subsetting a data frame based on Sample ID numbers in stored in a factor

Tags: r, subset

I have dataframe consisting of two columns, one with my sample IDs and and the other with my results, like such:

```
   Sample.ID Conc.
1         B1 0.020885051
2         B2 0.002398214
3         B3 0.001343366
4         B4 0.001501216
5         B5 0.002057419
6         B6 0.200243098
7         B7 0.003307670
8         B8 0.001403119
9          1 0.003150129
10         2 0.014822015
11         3 0.012500499
12       St2 0.199572365
13         4 0.012261783
14         5 0.004802208
15         6 0.003964603
16       St4 0.990239557
17         7 0.077453817
18         8 0.059765216
19       St2 0.204757306
20         9 0.061966809
```

I was wondering if there was an easy way to subset the data so in the end I had separate data frames for my B's:

```
Sample.ID Conc.
1         B1 0.020885051
2         B2 0.002398214
3         B3 0.001343366
4         B4 0.001501216
5         B5 0.002057419
6         B6 0.200243098
7         B7 0.003307670
8         B8 0.001403119
```

and my Numbers

```
Sample.ID Conc.
1          1 0.003150129
2          2 0.014822015
3          3 0.012500499
4          4 0.012261783
5          5 0.004802208
6          6 0.003964603
7          7 0.077453817
8          8 0.059765216
9          9 0.061966809
```

and finally my St's

```
Sample.ID Conc.
1        St2 0.199572365
2        St4 0.990239557
3        St2 0.204757306
```

Thanks for reading to the end & for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can split the data.frame using `split()`, and as long as your IDs are of the format letters-then-numbers you can strip off the trailing numbers using `gsub` as in:

```
stringsPart <-gsub('[0-9]*$','',myData$Sample.ID)
listOfSubDataFrames <- split(myData,stringsPart)
```

By the way, the regular expression matches zero or more (`*`) numbers (`[0-9]`) that appear at the end of the string (`$`), and gsub replaces them with the empty string (`''`).